# A GNU tool, or An GNU tool?

Tags: grammaticality, indirect-objects, sandhi

When writing a sentence about the GNU tools, how is the “a”/“an” used when describing a specific GNU tool?

```
Gawk, a GNU tool, performs the …
```

or

```
Gawk, an GNU tool, performs the …
```

Comment: Why would you use 'an'? There isn't a following vowel.

Comment: ... 'There isn't a gnu in sight' and equally 'There isn't a 'g' in view'. Where acronyms / initialisms begin with a vowel [sound], it's always 'an'. The a/an choice is always governed by how the next entity read out sounds ... well almost (see 'an hotel?')

Comment: In my experience, people pronounce the 'G' in GNU, so it would be "a GNU tool".

Comment: Yes, ⟨[gnu](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gnu)⟩ antelope can be pronounced without /g/, but ⟨[GNU](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/GNU)⟩ group-of-software-projects [officially](https://www.gnu.org/gnu/pronunciation.html) has pronunciation /ɡnuː/.

Comment: There is no way you can pronounce "GNU" that would require "an", whether it's "new" or "G - N - U". The tags are totally wrong too.

Comment: @user888379 whether g-nu or nu, there is still no reason for 'an'.

Comment: @WeatherVane D'oh! You are, of course, correct.